# how to edit existing video using GPUImage and resave it in device library

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, gpuimage

I want to edit the video using GPUImage which is already saved in device library. After editing, re-save edited video in device library.
Please Help....
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Sir, Have you found any tutorial?
I have [same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29917481/unable-to-edit-video-using-gpuimage) issue. Can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

Here is good tutorial:

http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2012/02/12/introducing-gpuimage-framework

See "Filtering and re-encoding a movie" section.