# Unable to edit video using GPUImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, gpuimage

I have created video using AVFoundation and now I want to edit it via GPUImage framework.
 I have set all the setting as per mention [here](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage). After seeing his example of "SimpleVideoFileFilter" I have just copied his code and replace my Assets URL for Video. Here is the code.

```
movieFile = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithURL:player.contentURL];
pixellateFilter = [[GPUImagePixellateFilter alloc] init];

[movieFile addTarget:pixellateFilter];

NSString *pathToMovie = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Movie.m4v"];
unlink([pathToMovie UTF8String]);
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToMovie];

movieWriter = [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc] initWithMovieURL:movieURL size:CGSizeMake(480.0, 640.0)];
[pixellateFilter addTarget:movieWriter];

movieWriter.shouldPassthroughAudio = YES;
movieFile.audioEncodingTarget = movieWriter;
[movieFile enableSynchronizedEncodingUsingMovieWriter:movieWriter];

[movieWriter startRecording];
[movieFile startProcessing];

NSLog(@"precess started");
[movieWriter setCompletionBlock:^{
    [pixellateFilter removeTarget:movieWriter];
    [movieWriter finishRecording];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"completed");
    });
}];
```

But I'm getting following error.
[image: error in GPUImage]
Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Please post the code blocks and error message as `code blocks` instead of images.

Comment: The code which you are watching in image is not written by me.
You can see the file name  which is GPUImageMovieWriter.m

Comment: What is the value of `status`?

Comment: @BlackFrog, that is not written by me.... That is file from GPUImage.framework

Comment: When I put pointer on `status` it shows **36055** as value.

Comment: I know you copied the code, have you tried running the sample code?

Comment: @BlackFrog, yes When I ran sample code it works fine but just replacing with my assetsURL getting this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By reading [this](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/issues/1276#issuecomment-39695145) I knew that this error occur when video has no audio. 
Same issue I have. I have no Audio my asset(Video). So facing this error.

To solve this error I just replaced from

```
movieFile.audioEncodingTarget = movieWriter;
```

to

```
movieFile.audioEncodingTarget = nil;
```

and code works fine.

Comment: It is worked for me. iOS11.1.2 can't write video with filter. Other version iOS don't get this problem.

Comment: Now the way I create filtered video without audio. And combin the vdieo and the original video's audio tracks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the correct answer, but I hope it leads in the right direction.

`status` value of **36055** is **0x8CD7** - *Missing Attachment*.
Excerpt from Apple Discussion Forum - [GL Framebuffer Completeness & Blitting Issues](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3908778)

```
#define GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE                        0x8CD5
#define GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT           0x8CD6
#define GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MISSING_ATTACHMENT   0x8CD7
#define GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DRAW_BUFFER          0x8CDB
#define GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_READ_BUFFER          0x8CDC
#define GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED                     0x8CDD
```

According to forum,

> It turned out you have to call:
>
> glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE)
>   glReadBuffer(GL_NONE)
>
> on BOTH the source and destination buffers. i.e Both buffers have to
>   be read and draw complete.
>
> This was why I got a seemingly flipped status on the buffers when I
>   checked them.
>
> Cheers.
>   YJ